# Pass multiple Value to class from function

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have 2 class 1 is get ms access data and another class for sql acsess.
i want to pass acsess class function value to sql class and assign it to sql class varible.curruntly i can assign only 1 varible.

```
Public Class connectionclass
Dim provider As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=|DataDirectory|"
Dim database As String = "serverdata.accdb"
Public connstring As String = provider & database
Public myconnection As New OleDbConnection(connstring)
Public Function data1()
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim u As String
    Dim p As String
    Try
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim getdata As New OleDbCommand("select * from server", myconnection)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = getdata.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            x = reader.Item("sname")
            y = reader.Item("dbase")
            u = reader.Item("username")
            p = reader.Item("password")
            Return (x)
        End While
        myconnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

End Class

2nd class

```
ublic Class datbaseconnect
Public obj1 As New connectionclass
Dim returnvalue As String
Dim X = obj1.data1
Dim y = ""
Dim u = ""
Dim p = ""
Public SQLCon As New SqlConnection With
  {.ConnectionString =
  "Server=" & x & ";
    DataBase=" & y & ";
    user ID=" & u & ";
    password=" & p & ";
    Trusted_Connection=false;
"}

End Class
```

Comment: Please don't ever write `Catch ex As Exception : ... : End Try` - it's a bad practice. Always let these exceptions bubble up and only ever catch specific exceptions (not just `Exception`) that you can meaningfully handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tuples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx) are a quick and easy way to return multiple data values in a single variable without having to create a whole new class to hold the individual values.

```
Public Function data1() As Tuple(Of String, String, String, String)
    Dim x As String
    Dim y As String
    Dim u As String
    Dim p As String
    Try
        myconnection.Open()
        Dim getdata As New OleDbCommand("select * from server", myconnection)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = getdata.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            x = reader.Item("sname")
            y = reader.Item("dbase")
            u = reader.Item("username")
            p = reader.Item("password")
            Return New Tuple(Of String, String, String, String)(x, y, u, p)
        End While
        myconnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

When calling this function it will return data like:

```
Dim returnedData = data1()
```

Finally, you simply call the function like:

```
WorkWithData(returnedData)
```

I wasn't able to include your own second class as I didn't see a function in there.

```
Public Sub WorkWithData(incomingData As Tuple(Of String, String, String, String))
    Debug.Print(incomingData.Item1)
    Debug.Print(incomingData.Item2)
    Debug.Print(incomingData.Item3)
    Debug.Print(incomingData.Item4)
End Sub
```